# Iphone Linker Error – “class.o for architecture i386" confused?

Tags: iphone

I am getting error  Linker Error – class.o for architecture i386 on xcode project while i try to build the project. on my project i have used some third party framworks as well. any solution for this ??

Comment: can you provide a complete error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To break down this issue here are some tips.

1>Make sure to included the QuartzCore framework  or other required frameworks in your project. It should be in the Build Phases->Link Binary With Libraries.

3>Check while  switching to the new version, you put the new library in a folder next to the old one, in case you had to switch back at some point. Normally when you removed the old version, it did not remove the path to the old version of the .a file from Library Search Paths in the build settings in "Project Name -> Under Targets" and delete the old path and add new one if required.

2>To add new class please select  Project Name -> Under Targets select your target project name -> Build Phases -> Expand Compile Sources -> Click + at bottom of Compile sources and add the correct source file.

4>If the above tips are not working for you then be careful while adding files , don’t copy files directly, just create class  by clicking on "new files" in Xcode and copy code one by one  and add required frameworks. it won't show linker error .

Answer (score 1):

I believe the class is not in your compile sources list.

Select your project on the navigation sidebar -> goto "build phases" -> expand "compile sources" -> add the corrensponding .m file for your class

Answer (score 1):

Please check the class for which you are getting error message is linked to the target you are building.

Also make sure the third party library you are linking into project is properly linked and also linked at runtime of the project.

That is sure that application is able to find the class which you have mentioned at runtime.